# Why is my EJB3,1 timer running on both server instances?

Tags: java, timer, ejb-3.1

We have a @Singleton EJB that is running a timer with a timeout method created by the following annotation:

```
@Schedule(hour = "*", minute = "*/5", second = "0")
public void processCodes() {
```

For a long time it would run only on a single instance of the clustered server, but now it insists on running on both instances, which is causing duplicate work.

We added 'persistent', like so:

```
@Schedule(hour = "*", minute = "*/5", second = "0", persistent = true)
public void processCodes() {
```

even though that's supposed to be the default.  It still runs on both servers.  Is there some server setting I should check to make sure the cluster is properly created?

Any suggestions on what to try or where to look next would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks!
Peter

Comment: What's the *vendor* (IBM Websphere, Oracle Glassfish, etc.) of the Application Server?

Comment: Sorry.  WebSphere 8.0.0.6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, the EJB container uses a server-specific database to hold persistent timers.  In a clustered (network deployed) environment, you need to configure the EJB container to use a data source that points to a common database.  The easiest way to do this is to configure the EJB timer service to use a custom data source, but you can also configure the EJB timer service to use a custom scheduler with the custom data source.  There is more information in the [Configuring a timer service for network deployment](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.0.0/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/info/ae/ae/tejb_timercluster_v8.html) topic in the knowledge center.

Comment: So, basically the answer is, can't do it without some configuration.  Which means that it working before was a fluke.  Well, thank you for the information.  Thanks!